# What ways are there for handling a double click event without using codebehind?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, code-behind, routed-events

I saw [an article detailing how to do this using attached behaviors](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/) which I like a lot.  However, the download doesn't work and the article is pretty old (a couple of years).

What is the current way for handling events like this without using codebehind?  Are there any that are MVVM-specific?

Comment: I still use the code shown in that article and it hasn't given me trouble yet :) I believe you can use Expression's Interaction Triggers, but I've personally never used them so can't say if they're better or worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the expression blend extensions:

```
<ListBox>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="CommandNameHere"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListBox>
```

It is another dependency, but it does seem to work well in .NET 4.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=10801

Edit: You can also use the CommandParameter To Pass In Extra Things (Like The Selected Item View Model)